# How to resize images without keep the ratio

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I tend to resize an image from large size into 584*565. I tried some methods but they all keep the ratio which means I can resize width into 584 but the height is not 565. My code is :

```
fd_img = open('path/123.jpg', 'r')
img = Image.open(fd_img)
img = resizeimage.resize('thumbnail', img, [584, 565])
img.save('path/123.gif', img.format)
fd_img.close()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using some particular library/module?

Comment: resizeimage and PIL